# PHP Database Session Handling ignoring MySQL Login credentials

Tags: php, mysql, session

I recently migrated an application from one server to another (much newer) server. After the move, my database session handling is no longer working. When I attempt to log in, I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO) w/ucr-dev/includes/DatabaseSessionHandler.class.php on line 44
```

The user www-data is not the database user I specified, and is not a valid user for the Database. When I was initially writing this application I wrote a blog entry detailing the exact steps and all code required. That blog entry can be found at [My Blog](http://brennydoogles.wordpress.com/2011/09/06/taking-control-of-your-php-sessions-using-database-sessions/).

Any Ideas?

Comment: Side note: you might consider looking into [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or at least [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your database connection hasn't been opened yet when `mysql_real_escape_string()` is called. That function requires an open database connection to work. If one isn't specified, it assumes the last connection that has been opened. If no connection is open, it will implicitly call `mysql_connect()` with no parameters.  Thus the reason it's trying to connect with the webserver's user `www-data` and with no password.

It seems like you might want to call `$this->open()` inside `MySQLDatabase::__construct()` so that the connection is opened when the object is created.